# Who approves flight plans for repetitive helicopter rides at local festivals in the US?

Tags: helicopter

The helicopters are taking off and landing in a public park located in the midst of a residential area.

Comment: A "Flight Plan" has a very specific meaning within aviation, which I would guess is not the purpose of your question.  (I could be wrong). Are you asking who approves repetitive helicopter rides at local festivals in the U.S.? (Disregarding the words "Flight Plan")

Answer (score 2):

The question, as asked, is "nobody". Flight plans don't need to be approved by anyone. Flight plans are *filed* by pilots (or, for big commercial or charter operations, by the planning department of the company) solely in order to tell ATC where the pilot plans to fly.*

(If they're within the controlled airspace of a nearby airport, they'd need to contact that airport over the radio for permission every time they took off, but I don't think that's exactly what you're asking.)

For the specific helicopters you're talking about, though, its highly likely that there is no flight plan at all. You don't need to file a flight plan to fly in the US, so if all they're doing is taking some passengers sightseeing/joyriding, I doubt they'd bother.

Now, if the park is inside the city limits, there may be some noise ordnance or zoning rule that would need to be set aside, but answering that is beyond the scope of aviation.se. You'd need to contact the city council/board/alderman/whatever to ask about that one.

*Well, IFR flight plans can be modified by ATC when they're activated, which I guess could count as a form of "approval" depending on your point of view.

Comment: You touched on this a little... to be precise, the flight ***plan*** does not need to be approved by anyone, but the ***clearance*** is whatever ATC gives you. From that moment on the "plan" is all but irrelevant. Also note that (at least in the USA) a filed VFR flight plan is not helpful in telling ATC where you plan to fly, because VFR flight plans are not viewable by ATC.